# Can't start Linux after deleting core dumps

Tags: root-filesystem, core-dump, system-recovery

My root partition had no space to the point that couldn't login.

So invoked <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and ran to free disk space:

```
find / -xdev -name core -ls -o  -path "/lib*" -delete
```

Now can't even initialize OS after GRUB, it days:

```
run-init: can't execute '/sbin/init' No such file or directory
run-init: can't execute '/etc/init' No such file or directory
run-init: can't execute '/bin/init' No such file or directory
```

How can solve that?

Comment: At least in RPM based distros it's trivial to find missing files for the installed packages and there's no need to reinstall anything - you could simply reinstall the damaged packages. Probably reinstalling the kernel will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You deleted a lot of kernel stuff. For example:

```
kernel/drivers/infiniband/core
kernel/drivers/memstick/core
kernel/drivers/mmc/core
kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/mellanox/mlx5/core
kernel/drivers/usb/core
kernel/drivers/video/fbdev/core
kernel/net/core
kernel/sound/core
kernel/drivers/infiniband/core
kernel/drivers/memstick/core
kernel/drivers/mmc/core
kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/mellanox/mlx5/core
kernel/drivers/usb/core
kernel/drivers/video/fbdev/core
kernel/net/core
kernel/sound/core
kernel/drivers/infiniband/core
kernel/drivers/memstick/core
kernel/drivers/mmc/core
kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/mellanox/mlx5/core
kernel/drivers/usb/core
kernel/drivers/video/fbdev/core
kernel/net/core
kernel/sound/core
```

If you have no backup, you should reinstall your computer (and use LVM).

Comment: there's no way to use a recovery image or whatever?

Comment: No they didn't, they did something more creative than that. Notice the `-o` in their `find` command: they execute `-ls` for anything named `core`, but `-delete` for anything matching the path pattern `/lib/*`.  If you suggest restoring these files from backup, you should also suggest how they may do that, as they can't boot their system.

Comment: there's a way to recover that?

Comment: @jck Personally, I would reinstall everything, then restore important data (home directory files, most likely) from an external backup.

Comment: @jck: If you are afraid of data loss, I would start with a live-CD and copy the needed data to an external drive. 
In theory you could try to find the deleted files in a similar installation and copy them back. From my point of view this is more work and also not guaranteed that it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Have decided to use a LiveOS to save all my data and reinstall the whole OS.

Thank you for advice.

Now I see that 30 GB for the `root` partition isn't enough (it had all the filesystem except `/home`).